# remove public static function wp_link_dialog()

Tags: php, functions, editor

How can remove public static function wp_link_dialog() from class-wp-editor.php by adding a code inside function.php of my theme?

My theme use WordPress editor at the frontend of the site and this code is added to the page source of my site and causes many of issues for me.

The problem that if I removed it from the class-wp-editor.php any updates from WordPress will be added it again.

Comment: since the [_WP_Editors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_editors/) class is final there is no way to "remove" any of its methods. what problems is it causing?  that will help us figure out some other workaround for you.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron  the issue about <h1 id="link-modal-title"><?php _e( 'Insert/edit link' ) ?></h1> i want to replace h1 to span but with php not javascript.

Comment: WHY does having it be an h1 cause problems?

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron Because I have already my h1 title and two h1 inside the page is not good for SEO because that i need to replace h1 to span for link-modal-title.

Comment: SEO is a black art.  Since **none** of the search engines document their algorithms, **much** of what is written about SEO is pure _speculation_.  While many h1s on a page was _likely_ bad for SEO pre-HTML5, it is _likely_ not a problem now  (see [The Truth About Multiple H1 Tags in the HTML5 Era](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824) and [Quick Overview: SEO and Multiple H1 Tags](https://www.greenlaneseo.com/blog/seo-101-seo-and-multiple-h1-tags/)).   I would **not** worry about this particular case of multiple h1s.

Comment: If you do want to limit to 1 h1 in this case, then JS is your only option.

Comment: Can't use str_replace but for the whole page? PHP

Comment: not in this case...as `_WP_Editors::wp_link_dialog()` directly echos its output.  You **might** be able to hack something up using PHP's [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) & [ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) but such a solution is out-of-scope for WPSE (and simply using JS would be **much** easier)..

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron Okay how can do this? Directly using remove() in javascript? I try this but it's not working with wp_link_dialog() content I can remove anything from the page but when to try to remove wp_link_dialog() by adding wp-link-wrap id it's back again.